# Regex for Grafana PromQL

Tags: regex, grafana, promql

I want to transform the `kube_node_info{node="ip-10-1-15-18.ap-south-1.compute.internal"}` using the transform by regex but unable to do the same. I want to have node value like `ip-10-1-15-18`

[image]
Have tried the regex like above but seems it's not giving the expected results.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following *pattern*.  Replace the entire match, with *group 1*.

```
(?<=node=\")([^.]+).+(?=\")
```

Answer (score 0):

*Rename by regex* is a wrong tool for the job: it is used to rename fields, not to change content of the field.

Use [`label_replace`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace) function of promQL in your query instead:

```
label_replace(kube_node_info, "node_ip", "$1", "node", "(ip-[a-zA-Z0-9-]+).*")
```

If it's guaranteed that first segment of label `node` is unique for for every node, you can use `node` instead of `node_ip` to replace content of the label in-place.

Demo of similar query [here](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=up&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h&g1.expr=label_replace(up%2C%20%22first_domain%22%2C%20%22%241%22%2C%20%22instance%22%2C%20%22(%3F%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2F)%3F(%5C%5Cw%2B).*%22)&g1.tab=1&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=1h&g2.expr=label_replace(absent(non_existent%7Bnode%3D%22ip-1-a-D.asd.asd%22%7D)%2C%20%22node_ip%22%2C%20%22%241%22%2C%20%22node%22%2C%20%22(ip-%5Ba-zA-Z0-9-%5D%2B).*%22)%20&g2.tab=1&g2.stacked=0&g2.range_input=1h).